# Avocado seeds are really slow this year

Tags: germination, avocado

I’ve managed to grow several avocados from seed in the past, however this year the ones I put in jars have taken forever to progress. All my previous attempts have produced a single main root and grown into healthy plants that have been surviving outside even in British winters.
But theses two this year are really struggling. One has 7 roots coming off it and still the shoot hasn’t reached beyond the top of the seed  the other has a single root they is starting to fork at the tip and has year to come out either. They’ve both been sprouting for about 3 months (more or less).
Today I noticed white nodules, so I did a little and cleaned them off and put them in fresh water.
Any ideas what I should do?

I’ve heard hydrogen peroxide is good for plants (I’ve several litres for other hobbies)[[image: Avocado 1][1]]

[3]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7GA7.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7GA7.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cKvl.jpg)[image]